# Solr - combine geodist with other query fields

Tags: solr, lucene, geospatial, geocoding

I am trying to add additional query options to a Solr query that uses the function geodist. The query doesn't break, but it doesn't actually seem to be changing the score of the documents and therefore not affecting the order of the results. Also, how would I control the weight / importance of each in a working version of this query.

I'm trying to express this in the query field (q) in Solr.

`state_licenses:TX and _query_:"{!func}geodist(location_pt,35.9,-80.1)"`

URL:
http://localhost:8983/solr/locations/select?fl=*%2Cscore&indent=true&q.op=OR&q=state_licenses%3ATX%20and%0A_query_%3A%22%7B!func%7Dgeodist(location_pt%2C35.08%2C-80.89)%22&rows=10&sort=score%20asc&start=0

I feel like this code sample may be heading in the right direction. But can't see how I combine q terms with the distance in the sort.

`http://localhost:8983/solr/geospatial/select?   sort=$distance asc&   fl=id,distance:$distance&   q=*:*&   distance=query($distFilter)&   distFilter={!geofilt pt=37.775,-122.419 sfield=location_rpt d=5 score=distance filter=true}`